# My iTunes sync completes, but my iPod doesn't get any music. What can be done?

Tags: itunes, data-synchronization, ipod, ipod-shuffle

Device : iPod Shuffle 2nd Second Generation
OS     : Windows 7 64 bit

My steps were as follows

[image]

I checked the "Sync only checked songs"

[image]

Even though i checked some songs before syncing, i did not find any of them in my iPod. The sync completed without any error output.

Settings tab

[image]

Contents tab

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is an **Autofill** button that you must select (click) before syncing to get the music onto the device.

Answer (score 1):

Get info for the checked tracks and see if in the Options tab, Skip when Shuffling is checked. If so, those tracks won't sync to an iPod shuffle.

Answer (score -1):

As someone's said, the square button that says 'automatically fill space with songs' has to be ticked. I spent two hours trying to work out what was going wrong before finding this answer on here. The labelling of the button is misleading - iTunes only puts the songs you have ticked on your device, it doesn't randomly fill the whole thing.